# Split flat array into groups/chunks of N elements then sum each group

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sum, grouping

I need to get a valid timestamp from the following array:

```
$arrkeys = array(
    "t" => [
        1442238840,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540,600,660,720,780,840,900,960,
        1442239860,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540,600,660,720,780,840,900,960,
        1442240880,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540,600,660,720,780,840,900,960
    ]
);
```

I need to sum the first valid timestamp `1442238840` with the following 17 numbers together, to get a correct timestamp, and then, the second timestamp `1442239860`, etc...

Example:

```
1442238840 + 60;
1442238840 + 120;
1442238840 + 180;
etc...
```

I can't figure out how I could do this,
some things I've tried:

**Attempt No. 1**

```
//Pseudo-code
foreach($arrkeys["t"] as $t){

    if(strlen($t) < 10){
        //Search for the first valid timestamp and sum?
    }

}
```

**Attempt No. 2**

```
//Not working.
$array_size = 17; 

/* I know that every 17 (counting from 0) have a  valid timestamp. 
    so that 0 = 1st valid timestamp, 20 = 2nd valid timestamp. */

for ($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++) { 
    do {
        echo $i;
    } while ($i > 0);
```

I don't know if I'm going the right way to solve this, I don't know how to do this efficiently, or at least do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your desired result is not clearly expressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love that you tried different things. That's good!

You tried to solve the problem yourself and [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) will help you a lot here, since you can chunk your array into groups of 17 elements and then use [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to sum each group of 17 elements together, e.g.

```
$result = array_chunk($arrkeys["t"], 17);
$result = array_map("array_sum", $result);
```